# Filtering Django data by dictionary and regular expression?

Tags: python, django, regex, database, web

I was trying to combine filtering Django data through a combination of dictionary and regular expression. So my dictionary looks like this:

```
dict = {key: r'.*?' + value + '.*?$'}
```

where I have key and value as string variables.

And I want to filter the data such that all the rows I retrieve have its key index's values contains the string value.

```
table.objects.all().filter(**dict)
```

However, this does not give me the rows I desire; in fact, it gives me no row at all while all the rows with index key should have shown. I'd appreciate any insights into what might have gone wrong here and how I can begin fixing it. Thank you!

Edit: I would prefer to use the Dictionary approach to filtering because I'm taking the keys to filter as a substring given in the URL parameters. If you think there is any other way I can retrieve the string from the URL and do something like:

```
table.objects.all().filter(key: r'.*?' + value '*?$' ).
```

I would appreciate it as well, just not sure how to do that given I only have variable key as a string!

Edit:  key is "city", value is "Philadelphi", and I'm looking for rows that have index "city" = "Philadelphia", but those do not show.

Comment: And what exactly are the values of the variable `key` and `value` here?

Comment: Is dict = `{key: r'.*?' + value '*?$'}` a valid dictionary? Aren't you missing a + after `value`?

Comment: @Dr.Regex My apologies, that's my typo! I changed it to {key: r'.*?' + value + '.*?$'}. However, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat key is "city", value is "Philadelphi", and I'm looking for rows that have index "city" = "Philadelphia", but those do not show.

Comment: Why not then just use `key__contains` method?

Comment: @Dr.Regex Could you elaborate more on that in the context of the filtering function? Are you suggesting that I can change `table.objects.all().filter(**dict)` to something like `table.objects.all().filter(key__contains=value)`?

Comment: @Đỗ Nguyên Tùng Yes, that would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that `key` is `"city"` and `value` is `"Philadelphi"`, if we replace these in the query you make you basically write:

```
table.objects.all().filter(city= r'.*?Philadelphi*?$')
```

If the problem is not yet visible, then when one doesn't specify a lookup it is automatically assumed to be an `exact` lookup, you instead want to either use the `regex` or `iregex` lookup. Also you should escape your value when you put it in a regex:

```
import re

key = '%s__iregex' % key
value = r'.*?%s.*?$' % re.escape(value)
dict = {key: value}

table.objects.all().filter(**dict)
```

Also as suggested in the comments your regex doesn't seem to be different from a `contains` lookup so unless you have some different regex you should use:

```
key = '%s__contains' % key
dict = {key: value}

table.objects.all().filter(**dict)
```

Comment: Thank you! That works for me now. May I ask what does the line `key = '%s__iregex' % key` do? Is it specifying that whenever I look up using that key, I want to apply regex to the value I'm looking at?

Comment: @ĐỗNguyênTùng since `key` is initially `"city"` then running `key = '%s__iregex' % key` would set it to `"city__iregex"`. `__` is how you separate lookups and if you want to use regex you use `regex` or `iregex` (for case insensitive). `string % some_variable` is just some normal python syntax to format a string, and it looks much more elegant than that concatenation. You could also use f-strings like `key = f"{key}__iregex"`, plus also the `format` method, etc.